# How to restart GUI on Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: desktop

On Ubuntu, you can type Alt-F2 to get the "Run Command" prompt, you can just type `r` there, and the desktop GUI will be restarted, without the need to log off and log on again ...

Here are a bit more details on this procedure for Ubuntu Gnome3: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-gui-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa

However, I cannot do the same on Raspbian Stretch:

[image: Alt-F2 R]

[image: Alt-F2 R fail]

... since Alt-F2 + `r` fails with: `Failed to execute child process "r" (No such file or directory)`.

The above link mentions that in Ubuntu Gnome3, Alt-F2 + `r` is equivalent to the commands:

- `gnome-shell --replace` (sudo not required); or
- `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` (sudo required).

I've tried `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` on Raspbian Stretch - but it looks like it does not restart the desktop GUI.

I also found this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518001/what-commands-are-run-by-altf2-and-r - and for cinnamon desktop, apparently the commands are:

- `pkill -HUP -f "cinnamon --replace"`
- `dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'global.reexec_self()'` (this is also for Gnome desktop)
- `dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.Cinnamon /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.Eval string:'global.reexec_self()'`

So - is there a similar "restart GUI" command that I can use in Raspbian without sudo? (I'm interested in the command line - but ultimately, I would want to put it as a shortcut in the Raspberry menu...)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. There are lots of ways, but there seems little point.

Comment: Thanks @Milliways - see below, just answered the question myself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found it - first I was wondering what is the desktop environment in Raspbian Stretch, and I found this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/ - and I thought it was called PIXEL.

But then, via https://itsfoss.com/find-desktop-environment/ I found out about `screenfetch`, so:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt install screenfetch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
Unpacking screenfetch (3.7.0-1) ...
Setting up screenfetch (3.7.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...

pi@raspberry:~ $ screenfetch 
    .',;:cc;,'.    .,;::c:,,.    pi@pi-boxcalmeas-05
   ,ooolcloooo:  'oooooccloo:    OS: Raspbian 9.13 stretch
   .looooc;;:ol  :oc;;:ooooo'    Kernel: armv7l Linux 4.19.66-v7+
     ;oooooo:      ,ooooooc.     Uptime: 1d 31m
       .,:;'.       .;:;'.       Packages: 1320
       .... ..'''''. ....        Shell: 3557
     .''.   ..'''''.  ..''.      Resolution: 1024x768
     ..  .....    .....  ..      DE: LXDE
    .  .'''''''  .''''''.  .     WM: OpenBox
  .'' .''''''''  .'''''''. ''.   CPU: ARMv7 rev 4 (v7l) @ 1.4GHz
  '''  '''''''    .''''''  '''   GPU: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 128 bits)
  .'    ........... ...    .'.   RAM: 153MiB / 926MiB
    ....    ''''''''.   .''.    
    '''''.  ''''''''. .'''''    
     '''''.  .'''''. .'''''.    
      ..''.     .    .''..      
            .'''''''            
             ......
```

Ok, so it's an LXDE desktop - and so I found this post: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/refresh-linux-desktop-without-rebooting/ which told me I need to use:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ lxpanelctl restart && openbox --restart
```

... and this indeed seems to reload/restart the desktop...

Adding menu items is discussed here: http://cagewebdev.com/raspberry-pi-adding-start-menu-items/ - and that page mentions instead:

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

... which to me seems to only "refresh" the top menu bar?

The Raspberry Pi logo is here:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ls -la /usr/share/icons/PiX/48x48/places/distributor-logo.png 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Sep 26  2018 /usr/share/icons/PiX/48x48/places/distributor-logo.png -> start-here.png
pi@raspberry:~ $ ls -la /usr/share/icons/PiX/48x48/places/start-here.png lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Sep 26  2018 /usr/share/icons/PiX/48x48/places/start-here.png -> rpi-logo.png
pi@raspberry:~ $ ls -la /usr/share/icons/PiX/48x48/places/rpi-logo.png 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3709 Sep 26  2018 /usr/share/icons/PiX/48x48/places/rpi-logo.png
```

I create a .desktop file via: `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/RestartRPiDesktop.desktop`, with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=RestartRPiDesktop
Comment=Restart the Raspbian Desktop GUI
Icon=/usr/share/icons/PiX/48x48/places/rpi-logo.png
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'lxpanelctl restart && openbox --restart'
Terminal=false
Categories=Graphics;
```

Then I did `lxpanelctl restart` - and there is a new item under Graphics in the menu:

[image: desktop menu icon]

... and it seems to restart/refresh the desktop GUI fine - so all is good ...

Comment: I would remove everything until the point where you describe the `.desktop` file. There's no point in describing how you discovered RPi OS is using LXDE/openbox.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.